# Is it good for SEO to link back from a subdomain to the main domain using web banner links with alt text?

Tags: seo, subdomain, links, banners

I want search engines to connect the domain and subdomain together.  eg: `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`.
Is my method of doing so a problem for SEO?

[image]

I want the main domain to link to the subdomain with dofollow links and anchor text but the subdomain to link back with web banner links and alt text.

Opposed to other methods of linking:

[image]

Is the first image correct in Google (SEO)?

Comment: I would say that using dofollow text links in both directions is most natural.  (Your illustration with the red X.)  Is there a reason that you don't want to do that?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I thought there was a problem with SEO

Comment: answer this" Is it good for SEO to link back from a subdomain to the main domain using web banner links with alt text? " ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.   I use bidirectional dofollow text links between my main domain and my subdomains.   I don't know of any SEO problems with doing it my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely OK to dofollow link among domain and subdomain.

It *could* be a problem with dofollow linking, if you link two TLD domains among each other - in this case Google *could* suspect a PBN building, which is against its guidelines about manipulation of link juice flow. In case of TLD domains it is recommended to link with nofollow.

Comment: Does link via web banner also dofollow? A text link ( dofollow ) in one direction and web banner in other direction? Like the first image. thank you

Comment: @tooraj Any href link `<a href="">anchor</a>` with any anchor content (image, text) you create is automatically dofollow, until you explicitely add to it `rel="nofollow"`.